# Does audit logging plugin create audit log table in database?

Tags: grails, audit-logging

I have a grails project and I'm auditing some domain classes, I want to see the information saved by the audit logging plugin but I can't find where the audit_log is created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you install the audit logging plugin it should add automatically add a `audit_log` table to your database if your `dbCreate` setting in `DataSource.groovy` is one of

- `create`
- `create-drop`
- `update`

I'm assuming you're using Grails 1.X or 2.X?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.4.3

Comment: @RuS1991 then I stand by my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use the database-migration plugin, you need to perform "grails dbm-gorm-diff" to create a migration patch for the audit log table to be created the next time you start your application.